# Circular doubly linked list memory deallocation

Tags: c++, valgrind, heap-memory

I am having serious trouble cleaning up the memory of my circular linked list. I think I understand the issue though. My head pointer has, say, N allocations and my build pointer has N-1 allocations. The addback function can only have an integer and I can't use containers or vectors.

```
void Queue::addBack(int passed_Val)
{
    if (head == nullptr) //takes care of first node when list is empty
    {

        head = new QueueNode;//head is my building now
        cout<<"head is "<<sizeof(head)<<" bytes"<<endl;
        head->val = passed_Val;
        head->next = head;//this make an infinite loop
        head->prev = head;
        cout<<"node[0] mem allocated "<<head<<endl;

    }
    else 
    {
        //build next will always have N-1 address, where N = number of addresses
        //head points to. I don't want build to point to head when N=1
        //          have tempPtr point to old address                               
        QueueNode* tempPrev = head->prev;//this will always point to the last node added!   
        QueueNode* build = new QueueNode;
        build->next=head;
        cout<<"build is "<<sizeof(build)<<" bytes"<<endl;
        cout<<"node[1] mem allocated "<< build <<endl;
        cout<<"node[1] "<< head <<endl;
        build->val=passed_Val;

        build->next = head;
        head->prev = build;

        tempPrev->next = build;
        build->prev = tempPrev;

    }
```

and my destructor looks like this

```
Queue::~Queue()
{
    if(head !=nullptr)//needed because i don't want to deallocate head if it was never called
    {
        QueueNode* deletePtr = head->next;
            cout<<"deallocating node[0] "<<head<<endl;
            delete head;

            while(deletePtr !=head)
            {
                delete deletePtr;
                cout<<"deallocating pointer "<<deletePtr<<endl;
                deletePtr =deletePtr->next;
            }           
    }
}
```

I've thought about having the build pointer equal to the head pointer in the (head == nullptr) conditional but I am running into even more problems. Here is the result of my valgrind

[image]

I am thinking this line is my primary problem
==30923==  Address 0x5a225e0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd

So if I understand correctly, I am trying to deallocate memory that has already been freed? How can I fix this in my destructor? I've tried messing around with my addback function but I end up losing nodes or more memory leaks :(

Comment: A common cause of this is breaking the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Are you doing this? Can't really say with the code given.

Answer (score 3):

```
            delete deletePtr;
```

This destroys whatever object `deletePtr` was referencing. Immediately afterwards:

```
            deletePtr =deletePtr->next;
```

This attempts to reference `deletePtr->next`. As we've just determined, `deletePtr`'s object has been destroyed, and dereferencing it becomes undefined behavior.

This may or may not be the only problem with the shown code. It's not possible to conclusively determine this without a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there may be other problems; but this is definitely one of them.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer given by @SamVarshavchick, the code is flawed here:

```
delete head;
while(deletePtr != head)  // <-- You are comparing deletePtr to a deleted pointer?
```

Given all that, the `Queue` destructor seems to bes more complex than it should be.  The following is what I would have expected:

```
Queue::~Queue()
{
    QueueNode* deletePtr = head;
    QueueNode* nextPtr = nullptr;
    while ( deletePtr )
    {
       nextPtr = deletePtr->next;
       delete deletePtr;
       deletePtr = nextPtr;
    }
}
```

Note that there is no need to explicitly check for `head` being null at the beginning of the function, as the `while` loop will only be entered on a non-null value.

Answer (score 1):

I was the destructor! Here is how I solved it

```
Queue::~Queue()
{
    int i=1;
    if(head !=nullptr)//needed because i don't want to deallocate head if it was never called
    {

        QueueNode* stop = head->prev;

        QueueNode* deletePtr = head->next;//tractor node[1]
        QueueNode* temp = head;// cutter            node[0]

        if(deletePtr ==head)// N=1
        {
            delete deletePtr;
        }
        else if(deletePtr == stop)//N=2
        {
             deletePtr = stop;
             delete deletePtr; 
             delete head;
        }
        else//N >=3
        {   
            while (temp != stop)//last node
            {
                delete temp;      //delete node[0]
                cout<<"temp "<<temp<<endl;
                cout<<"deletePtr "<<deletePtr<<endl;
                temp= deletePtr;// node[1]                                         
                deletePtr = deletePtr->next;//node[2]       
                cout<<"temp "<<temp<<endl;
                cout<<"deletePtr "<<deletePtr<<endl;


            }       
            delete stop;
        }//end N>=3

    }
}
```